# How to prove two models beta variances' relationship

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, econometrics

I have two models: 1. $y=bx$ ($a=0$) 2. $y=\alpha+\beta x$. I have to calculate the variance of $b$ and then show that $\operatorname{var}(b)\leqslant \operatorname{var}(\beta)$. The estimate of b is b=(Σxy)/(Σx^2) while β=(Σxy-αΣx)/(Σx^2) and sum runs from i=1 to n. However, I do not see where to start or how to do it.

Comment: Neither $b$ nor $\beta$ have variances: they are *parameters,* not random variables.  Perhaps this question concerns the variances of parameter *estimates*?  If so, please explain how you intend to estimate them.  See our help on [tag:self-study] for more information.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry you're right. This concerns the variances of parameter estimates. I modify the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\hat b = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}$ and $\hat \beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar X)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}$ (it equals to OP's $\beta$). Assume that $\mathrm{Var}(y_i) = \sigma^2$ for $i = 1,...,n$ and $y_i$ are independent.

Then 
$$\mathrm{Var}(\hat b) =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 \mathrm{Var}(y_i)}{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2)^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} $$
$$\mathrm{Var}(\hat \beta) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}$$

We know that $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 - n\bar x ^2$. So $ {\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} \ge {\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}$.

Therefore $\mathrm{Var}(\hat b) \le \mathrm{Var}(\hat \beta)$.